# Selecting wrapper div instead of children with event delegation (e.target)

Tags: javascript

So I have something like this:

**HTML**

```
 <div class='test'>
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        if (e.target.className == 'test') {
          console.log(e.target);
        }
      }
    });
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to select the div with the class test, not the children elements. I could do e.target.parentNode but that is not accurate depending on the situation.

What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I print out test?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('test').addEventListener("click", 
    function(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Well I cant do that because I will have many test classes and I need to do specific things that require me to get the current test that has been clicked. I dont want to use loops.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well e.target should be "test". Thats all im trying to do using the code ive shown